# How the get the value from text field of html into JavaScript funtion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to get the form submitted value into where "'ZIP='Need form submitted value here'"

I get stuck here any help would be appreciative,I am beginner learner and  am developing Google maps.

//here is my code

```
<html>
<script  type="text/javaScript">>
    function onColorSelect_changed() {
        //document.getElementById('address').value

            var options = {
              styles : []
            };
            var styles = [];
            var selectEle = this;

            if (selectEle.selectedIndex == 0) {
              return;
            }

            options.styles.push({


                where: "'ZIP' = '89020'",
                polygonOptions: {
                  fillColor: selectEle.value,
                  strokeColor: "#FFFFFF",
                  strokeWeight: 3
                }
              });
            layer.setOptions(options);
          }






        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
      </script>
    </head>
      <body>
      <div id="map_canvas">
          <select id="colorSelector">
            <option >--Select color--</option>  
            <option value="#ffff00">#FFFF00</option>
            <option value="#ff00ff">#FF00FF</option>
            <option value="#f0f0f0">#F0F0F0</option>
          </select>

        </div>
      <h1 style="color:MediumAquaMarine ;">Zip code map search US</h1>
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
        <div style="margin-top: 10px;">
          <label class="layer-wizard-search-label">
            ZIP
            <input type="text" id="address" placeholder="Enter Zip code">
            <input id="geocode" type="button" onclick="codeAddress(document.getElementById('address').value);" value="Submit"></input>

    <div id="map_canvas"></div> 


          </label> 
        </div>

      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(#submit).click(function(){
   var address= document.getElementById('address');
   var value =address.val();
   }
```

value holds the zipcode